# How do I replace stages for opportunities with new stages, within Sandbox then push to production?

Tags: opportunity

I am trying to consolidate a long list of stages currently used into about 4 stages and need to replace the other stages with 1 of the 4 new ones.  How do I do this within Sandbox and then push to production with change sets? Or can this only be done directly in production?

Comment: It cannot be done via change sets (Standard objects / fields). You have to manually update them in production. You may be able to do it with ANT or other metadata tools but since I do not use them I cannot say.

Comment: So what is the actual process? I go to Stage in the opportunity section, click replace on the active stages section and then put the old and select the new?  Then do I delete the old from the active section?  Why doesnt it move to inactive?